# $\sum (a_i + x) \cdot \sum \frac{1}{a_i + x}$ is decreasing in $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $a_1$, $\ldots$, $a_n> 0$, not all equal.  Then the function

$$x \mapsto  ( (a_1 + x) + \cdots + (a_n + x) ) \cdot \left (\frac{1}{a_1 + x} + \cdots + \frac{1}{a_n + x} \right )$$

is strictly decreasing on $[0, \infty)$.

This should be well known, but don't recall seeing it anywhere.  If a repost please let me know.  Used the result to show that $(x+\frac{1}{2}) \log ( 1 + \frac{1}{x})$ is decreasing.

It turns out that the function is totally monotone, but that is just an extra result that somebody might be interested in.  If I recall, Keith Ball had a result about rational fractions that are totally monotone, so this could well be  a very particular case.

The idea would be  that the expression $\ge n^2$, and strictly so if $a_i$ are distinct, and adding $x$ to them makes them almost equal if $x$ is large.   Posted as [reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Any feedback would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that the following lemma can be established by expanding LHS and RHS.

$$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}=2+\frac{(a-b)^2}{ab}  \tag{1}$$

Let $$f(x)=\left( \sum_{i=1}^n (a_i+x) \right)\left( \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a_i+x} \right),$$
then
\begin{align}
f(x) &=\sum_{i=1}^n(a_i+x)\frac{1}{(a_i+x)} +\sum_{j=i+1}^n \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left( \frac{a_i+x}{a_j+x}+\frac{a_j+x}{a_i+x}\right) \\
& = n + \sum_{j=i+1}^n \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left( 
 2 + \frac{[(a_i+x)-(a_j+x)]^2}{(a_i+x)(a_j+x)}\right) \mathrm{by \  (1)} \\
&= n + \sum_{j=i+1}^n \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left( 
 2 + \frac{(a_i-a_j)^2}{(a_i+x)(a_j+x)}\right)  
\end{align}

Since all terms $$2+\frac{(a_i-a_j)^2}{(a_i+x)(a_j+x)}$$ in the summation are decreasing function of $x$ and some are strictly decreasing if $a_i$'s are not all equal, $f(x)$ is a strictly decreasing.

Furthermore,
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) & = \lim_{x \to \infty}\left [n + \sum_{j=i+1}^n \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left( 
 2 + \frac{(a_i-a_j)^2}{(a_i+x)(a_j+x)}\right) \right ]\\
& = n + \sum_{j=i+1}^n \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (2+0) \\
& = n + 2 \times \left[ (n-1)+(n-2)+ \dots + 1 \right] \\
& = n + 2 \times \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \\
& = n^2
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 5):

Obviously, you need to add the assumption that the $a_i$'s are not equal, otherwise the function is constant equal to $n^2$ and hence, not strictly decreasing.

So let's assume that the $a_i$'s are not all equal, and let $f : x \mapsto \Big( (a_1 + x) + \cdots + (a_n + x) \Big) \times \left(\dfrac{1}{a_1 + x} + \cdots + \dfrac{1}{a_n + x} \right)$.

Let's assume WLOG that $a_1 \leq a_2 \leq ... \leq a_n$.

One has
$$f(x)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i+x \right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^n \dfrac{1}{a_j+x} \right) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \dfrac{a_i+x}{a_j+x}= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n 1+\dfrac{a_i-a_j}{a_j+x}$$

Hence, one deduces that
\begin{align*} f'(x)& =-\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \dfrac{a_i-a_j}{(a_j+x)^2}\\
& =-\sum_{i>j} \dfrac{a_i-a_j}{(a_j+x)^2} + \dfrac{a_j-a_i}{(a_i+x)^2}\\
& =-\sum_{i>j} (a_i-a_j)\left[\dfrac{1}{(a_j+x)^2} - \dfrac{1}{(a_i+x)^2}\right]\\
& =-\sum_{i>j} (a_i-a_j)\left[\dfrac{(a_i+x)^2-(a_j+x)^2}{(a_i+x)^2(a_j+x)^2} \right]
\end{align*}

Since $a_i \geq a_j$ as soon as $i > j$, then each term of this sum is positive (and at least one of them is nonzero), and hence $f'(x) < 0$.

So $f$ is strictly decreasing.